# wmctrl bring on top doesn't work over fullscreen app

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, fullscreen

I've got a strange issue with wmctrl : I'm trying to bring on top a virtual keyboard with  by clicking on a button in another application (GUI app), but it seems not to work.
The other application (the GUI) is in Python created with the tkinter module.
It's strange because when the GUI is not in fullscreen mode it works fine, the Keyboard is bringing on top of the GUI. But when the GUI is set in fullscreen mode nothing appends, and I didn't get any error.
So if you have an idea I'm listening :)
thkx

Comment: Please show how you have created the GUI in fullscreen mode. Are you using the attribute `topmost`?

Comment: I tried with root.attributes('-fullscreen', 1) and with root.geometry and get the same problem

Comment: I ve got news ! I played with root.overdiredirected and discovered that the problem occured when there is no window border and decoration even when it isn t in fullscreen mode... but still have no solution.